# Algorithm need assistance

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm having some trouble thinking of an algorithm for my problem. I'll try to explain the best I can. This is just an example.

So say 3% of 1000 people clicked on a link.

So I need an algorithm that would spread a click randomly over 1000 views.

It's easy to spread it evenly eg: 1000 * .03 = 30, so every 30 views someone would click a link.

EG:

```
For (i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
if(i % 30 == 0);
click()
}
```

Comment: What is the probability that a click happens on any specific view?  How would you generate a random binary variable with that probability of being a 1?

Comment: Do you want the EXPECTED value of the outcome to be 3% of 1000, or for it to be exactly 3%?

Comment: It would be 3% of any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Boolean> wasclicked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLICKS * 0.03; i++) {
    wasclicked.add(true);
}
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLICKS * 0.97; i++) {
    wasclicked.add(false)
}
Collections.shuffle(wasclicked);
```

You now have a random list of booleans in which exactly 3% are true.

Comment: Exactly may not necessarily be exactly because of rounding.

Comment: Oh. Yes, that's true. If `NUM_CLICKS * 0.03` or `NUM_CLICKS * 0.97` is not an integer, that'll need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need actually 30 clicks or just a statistical distribution that provides 30 clicks per 1000 on average?  If a statistical distribution is all you need then just do `if (Math.random() < 0.03)`.  If you  need exactly 30 clicks, then the simplest way would be to choose 30 random numbers between 0 and 999, making sure you have no duplicates, and click on those indices.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create an array of 1000 integers, initialize 30 of them to 1 and the rest 970 to 0, then [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) the array randomly and use `array[index from 0 to 999]` to see if a click is needed.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea but not sure if it would perform well with large number such as 100,000